# margin between content and div overflow scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I am using the following bits of code to keep my menu items fixed while allowing for the scrolling of content because it seems to be the most stable method across all browsers.

```
body { overflow: hidden; }

div.content { height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
```

My problem is simple, and yet I can not seem to figure it out, the content inside the  tag butts up against the scrollbar for the div area and it makes reading much more difficult.  How can I get a margin between them (apart from floating a transparent image to the right to create space, there HAS to be a better way)?

Answer (score 0):

```
div.content { height: 100%; overflow: auto; margin:0 15px }
```

I might have misunderstood you though, post some HTML if I have.

Comment: I think you understood because that's the first thing I tried, too.  But that just increases the margin between the div space and the edge of the browser window, but the div scrollbar stays butted up against the content in the div section.

But... sr pt's suggestion did the trick.  I clearly need to get some sleep, or more coffee... for now, I'll opt for more coffee.

Comment: So what turned out to be the solution?