# Spacing between overflowing container and its scrollbar (pure CSS)

Tags: css

In a container with a scrollbar, how do I add a spacing between the contents and the scrollbar?

```css
.my-page
{
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5px;

  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;

  max-width: 200px; /*Comment this max-width to simulate the page becoming large enough for this container not to need a scrollbar*/
  
  padding-bottom: 5px; /*This padding adds a nice spacing between the container contents and its scrollbar, but if the page is large enough, it will cause the container to be higher than it needs to be*/
}

.box {
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.container2 {
  min-width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution should be pure CSS: I don't fancy adding observers to every scrollable object in my page, just to add a style when `container.scrollWidth > container.clientWidth`

[This 11 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559209/margin-between-content-and-div-overflow-scrollbar) does not have a proper answer.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. How high does the container "need to be" such that adding padding-bottom doesn't work?

Comment: When you remove `max-width` in `.container`, the scrollbar disappears. But then the red box stretches to the height of the blue ones *plus the padding*. Which leaves a jagged bottom edge. 
I'm looking for something like `row-gap` but for between content and scrollbar. A spacing that disappears when the scrollbar disappears.

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript for that. It is not feasible in CSS, unless you set an explicit height for both `.box` and `.container2`.

Comment: I agree with @TylerH. I could only find a similar solution. [Check out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68545034/16522884 "StackOverflow").

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, there will be a spacing between the container and the scrollbar, since the scrollbar will have the same background as the parent element.

In webkit browsers, estimated to be the case for 96% of the users, you can use:

**Webkit CSS styling properties for scrollbars**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar – the entire scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-track – the entire progress bar area of the scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb – the draggable section of the scrollbar
```

**The below properties are available but are less commonly used:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button – the up/down buttons at each end of the scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece – part of scrollbar not covered by the thumb
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner – bottom corner where horizontal and vertical scrollbars meet
```

**Firefox CSS styling properties for scrollbars**

There are currently only two available CSS properties for styling scrollbars in Firefox.

```
scrollbar-width – controls width of scrollbar, with only two options available being auto or thin
scrollbar-color – takes two colors which are used for the coloring of the thumb and track of the scrollbar in that order
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a more extensive minimal working example, I edited my question

Comment: Could you explain what else you need to know to accept this as an answer? You can edit the scrollbar in all browsers except Firefox, where there is already a gap anyway...

Comment: This is not an answer at all. You're stating that you can edit the scrollbar with those properties (which I'm already doing btw) but have you actually tried adding margin or padding or whatever to any of the properties? Because I cannot get a gap above a horizontal scrollbar or to the left of a vertical scrollbar. Not using those properties anyway.

Comment: Are we in agreement that in Firefox there is already a gap and that what you need help with is styling it for webkit browsers so that there is a gap? And can you please add the code you are using so that there is a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I think you could make it a bit easier to help you ;)

Comment: There's already a nice minimal reproducible example. If I remove the `padding-bottom: 5px;` from `.container` then there's no spacing between the blue boxes and the scrollbar. Not on Firefox either. The question is: is there a way to add an actual gap, à la `row-gap`? Or at the very least, some spacing that disappears when there's no need for a scrollbar? (Because that's where `padding-bottom` goes wrong: when there's no scrollbar, the padding remains and the red box is larger than the blue boxes by exactly that padding)

Comment: I've already tried giving the scrollbar padding by using the `::-webkit-scrollbar` properties, but padding/margins/etc only register in the wrong direction (i.e. to the left and right for a horizontal scrollbar)